# check for existence of a sheet in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to I check if `myname`
 sheet exist in google scripts, to avoid errors using `insertSheet` on an existing name?

Following does not work

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var itt = ss.getSheetByName('_EmailList');
  if (! (itt.hasNext())){
    ss.insertSheet('_EmailList');}
```

Comment: The `getSheetByName` method returns the sheet class.  The documentation actually shows an example of what you need:  `if (sheet != null) { //code here}`  I wouldn't check for undefined.  You could check for a falsy value.  `if (!itt) { //do something}`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It doesn't work because 'itt' is the instance of Sheet class that doesn't have 'hasNext()' method. Please be sure to review the docs before attempting to write code - this is guaranteed to save you a lot of trouble https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet

If the sheet with the specified name doesn't exist, getSheetByName() will return a null reference.

```
 var itt = ss.getSheetByName('_EmailList');

 if (!itt) {

   ss.insertSheet('_EmailList');
}
```

Comment: @Anton Dementiev So this will insert the sheet if it does not exist. Do I have to declare the sheet variable again since it now exists and didn't before?

Comment: I ran it as is and it is necessary to declare the variable again after sheet is inserted. Makes sense.