# Create a new sheet based on new names in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have a script that will automatically search a column `onSubmit` for a persons name and copy the row to a sheet based on this name. If the sheet doesn't exist, i would like it created automatically, the names are entered into column C.  The only answers to this i can find on StackOverflow are for when you know what names will appear. I do not know what the names will be. I tried this code by @CharlesHale but i can't get it to name the new sheet. Here is my code so far:

```
 function onFormSubmit() {
  // onFormSubmit
  // get submitted data
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1eCdLnyx9Y2159gS0yVUxZLRsZSHxEGw0zUp5MqdSHVw');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Col = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var headings = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,
Col).getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, Col);
  var name = sheet.getRange(row, Col).getValue();
  // check if username has sheet
  if(ss.getSheetByName(name)){
    var userSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    // if not make
  } else {
   var userSheet = ss.insertSheet(name);
    userSheet.getRange(1,1,1,
headings[0].length).setValues(headings);
  }
  // copy submitted data to user's sheet
  userSheet.appendRow(lastRow.getValues()[0]);
  userSheet.setColumnWidth(1, 500);
  userSheet.setColumnWidth(2, 500);
  var FormatSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
  var FormatRange = FormatSheet.getRange(1,1);
  FormatRange.copyFormatToRange(userSheet,1,3,3,28);
}
```

I've attached my sheets for reference. [Feedback form responses](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eCdLnyx9Y2159gS0yVUxZLRsZSHxEGw0zUp5MqdSHVw/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will allow you to check whether a sheet with this name exists and react accordingly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974770/check-for-existence-of-a-sheet-in-google-spreadsheets

Comment: This ought to get you going with using the value of a cell as a sheet name: [Dynamic generation of sheet name from cell content](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/84190/dynamic-generation-of-sheet-name-from-cell-content) and/or [Auto create and name new sheet in Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33518/auto-create-and-name-new-sheet-in-google-spreadsheet)