# How to auto-create a sheet based on named range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to be able to have the script create a new template sheet based on a named range from the base sheet. Also check for duplicate names and not create a new sheet if a duplicate exists.

```
function test() {
 var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

   // Get the range of cells that store employee data.
  var employeeDataRange = ss.getRangeByName("EmployeeRef");

  var employeeObjects = employeeDataRange.getValues();

  var template = ss.getSheetByName('Template');

  for (var i=0; i < employeeObjects.length; i++) {

     // Put the sheet you want to create in a variable
     var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(employeeObjects[i]);

      // Check if the sheet you want to create already exists. If so,
      // log this and loop back. If not, create the new sheet.
        if (sheet) {
           Logger.log("Sheet " + employeeObjects[i] + "already exists");
        } else {
           template.copyTo(ss).setName(employeeObjects[i]);
           }
        }
  return;
```

Comment: And what is the problem with this code?

Comment: It creates and extra sheet called "copy of template" every time I run the script

Comment: `getSheetByName` (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) returns null if there is no sheet with the given name. But your `if (sheet){` is not testing for null and so `template.copyTo` is ALWAYS successful. Instead do `if (!sheet){`; more details in [check for existence of a sheet in google spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974770/). Note the comment about being "necessary to declare the variable again after sheet is inserted"; interesting observation (though maybe not applicable here).