# Delete specific sheet if it already exists

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('export'), true); 
    spreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
```

This deletes a sheet called "export".
However, sometimes this sheet doesnt exist so the script gives me an error.
So i'd like to check first if a sheet called "export" exists, and delete it if so.
How do I do that, what syntax is needed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check for existence of a sheet in google spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48974770/check-for-existence-of-a-sheet-in-google-spreadsheets)

Comment: Almost... this might sound dumb, but your example takes action if the sheet doesnt exist - I want to take action (delete it) if it exists. I dont know how to modify that correctly.

Answer (score 3):

```
function deleteExport(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var itt = ss.getSheetByName('export');
  if (itt) {
    ss.deleteSheet(itt);
  }
};
```

If it doesn't find the sheet, it does nothing. Otherwise, it deletes the sheet named "export".

Reference:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet